# AMD RX580 Screen Tearing

Tags: release-juno

I've tried amd driver directly and it cause me to have the OS reinstalled.
Do advice on how i can solve the screen tearing thats going on.

Comment: Install your amd driver with  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to install the latest MESA drivers, you could add the official repositories

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade

They work very well in my case, even in games.

source:

https://translate.google.cl/translate?hl=es-419&sl=es&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muylinux.com%2F2017%2F03%2F28%2Fubuntu-ppa-mesa%2F

https://www.muylinux.com/2017/03/28/ubuntu-ppa-mesa/